# Proper use of a Lettrine when the paragraph begins with a roman numeral

Tags: paragraphs, typography, lettrine, roman-numerals, octavo

A typography consideration:

In a current project, I am encountering the situation where I would like to make use of a lettrine, but the paragraph in which it is to be used begins with a Roman numeral. When this happens, I am never quite certain of how to handle it: Should the numeral be placed atop the Lettrine in ordinary (or special) font; Should the numeral be placed to the left of the lettrine outside (or within) of the page margin; Should the numeral somehow be used in the (or some other) lettrine; etc.?

So, I ask to consider the code:

```
\documentclass[foolscap]{octavo}
\usepackage{lettrine,xcolor}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}

\input GoudyIn.fd
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\usefont{U}{GoudyIn}{xl}{n}}

\fboxsep=0pt % padding thickness
\fboxrule=0pt % border thickness

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent Paragraph in which a lettrine is to be incorporated:\\[10pt]

\noindent I. This is a paragraph which makes use of a lettrine; however, it is preceded by a Roman Numeral. \textbf{What is the proper way to handle a situation like this?}\\[10pt]

\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=.30,findent=.21em,nindent=2.5pt]{\fcolorbox{black}{red!70}{T\kern-.04em}}{his} is a paragraph which makes use of a lettrine; however, it is preceded by a Roman Numeral. \textbf{What is the proper way to handle a situation like this?}
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

QUESTION: How should a paragraph beginning with a Roman Numeral be handled when one wants to begin that paragraph with a lettrine?

Comment: Will you stop doing `\input Goudy.fd` instead of the proper LaTeX syntax `\input{Goudy.fd}`?

Comment: Anyway, this is not properly a TeX question: decide what you want do do and stick with it. How to achieve your choice can be a TeX question.

Comment: I suggest to make a copy of GoudyIn.fd called `uGoudyln.fd` and put is somewhere where latex can find it, then you will no longer have to input it manually.

Comment: a quick search failed to provide any examples so "don't do that" would be one answer, othewise I would guess using in-margin numbers to the left of the drop cap would just about work.

Comment: also please stop posting examples that produce `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 14--15`   remove the `\\ ` and `\noindent` you must know by now they are wrong.

Comment: @egreg `\input{Goudy.fd}` produces an error with me.

Comment: @mlchristians Sorry, `\input{GoudyIn.fd}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Are you referring to `\\[10pt]`? I see no other \\ --- As for \noindent, how do you prevent a paragraph from indenting? I believe you had recommended the use of `\\[]`  to me a while ago.

Comment: Not there, never use `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph.   If you want paragraphs to be unindented and separated by vertical space specify that at a document level eg add `\usepackage{parskip}`  badness 10000 is the _maximum_ value of badness, TeX is warning you in its strongest possible way no to do that.

Comment: @David Carlisle Thank you for your last comment, but when I posted the code it compiled without error. Your `\usepackage{parskip}` recommendation sounds like it will produce no indentation *for all* paragraphs. Correct  me if I am wrong. However, what do you suggest to do when one has code say, of 20,000 lines, and only needs three or four paragraphs not indented.

Comment: check your log: it give the underfull box warning in the log and on the terminal.  how is the reader supposed to know they are paragraphs if they use a different style? but you can use `\setlength\parindent{0pt}` locally, or use `\raggedright` locally, or perhaps they are not really paragraphs but forced linebreak, latex doesn't indent after `\\ ` so if you use `\\ ` instead of a blank line you get no indent.

Comment: I agree with David Carlisle: Don’t do this. The Roman numeral already sets the paragraph off, so the lettrine serves no purpose except decoration, and the decorative effect is spoiled by the numeral.

Comment: @Thérèse Though David Carlisle has posted three paragraphs with lettrines, are you saying not to use any of them; but rather, leave the paragraph with the Roman numeral alone, as is. If that is the case, would starting the second paragraph with the lettrine be OK? Or, should that particular chapter have no lettrine at all? Thank you. I appreciate your advice.

Comment: @Thérèse Would any of David Carlisle's paragraphs be good to use in your estimation. They do seem nicely done.

Comment: No, and he doesn’t like them himself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say I like any layout here but at least TeX doesn't scream about underfull boxes.

[image]

```
\documentclass[foolscap]{octavo}
\usepackage{lettrine,xcolor,parskip,lmodern}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{GoudyIn}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{GoudyIn}{xl}{n}{
   <-> GoudyIn
}{}

\NewDocumentCommand\PP{}{%
\refstepcounter{enumi}%
\raisebox{20pt}[0pt]{%
\makebox[0pt]{\normalfont\large\textbf{\Roman{enumi}.}\hspace{25pt}}}}

\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\usefont{U}{GoudyIn}{xl}{n}}

\fboxsep=0pt % padding thickness
\fboxrule=0pt % border thickness

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

Paragraph in which a lettrine is to be incorporated:

I. This is a paragraph which makes use of a lettrine; however, it is preceded by a Roman Numeral.
\textbf{What is the proper way to handle a situation like this?}

\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=.30,findent=.21em,nindent=2.5pt]{\fcolorbox{black}{red!70}{T\kern-.04em}}{his}
is a paragraph which makes use of a lettrine; however, it is preceded
by a Roman Numeral. \textbf{What is the proper way to handle a
  situation like this?}




\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=.30,findent=.21em,nindent=2.5pt]{\PP\fcolorbox{black}{red!70}{T\kern-.04em}}{his}
  is a paragraph which makes use of a lettrine; however, it is
  preceded by a Roman Numeral. \textbf{What is the proper way to
    handle a situation like this?}


\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=.30,findent=.21em,nindent=2.5pt]{\PP\fcolorbox{black}{red!70}{S\kern-.04em}}{econd}
  paragraph which makes use of a lettrine; however, it is
  preceded by a Roman Numeral. \textbf{What is the proper way to
    handle a situation like this?}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to post this.

Answer (score 1):

There are really two possible approaches for this based on precedents in typography.

One approach is that the list takes precedence over the drop cap so you would have something like:

> ### A Chapter title
>
> I. A numbered list that comes here.
>
> II. Because that's what's going on here with the numbered items. They're a list even if we aren't using an `enumerate` to generate them.

This is akin to how you wouldn't apply the drop cap to a section title that immediately follows a chapter where normally the drop caps appear on the first paragraph of the chapter.¹

The second option would be to omit the number on the first paragraph, akin to how the opening quotation mark is generally omitted when it would be part of a drop cap.²

---

1. And note that in this instance, you would *not* normally put the drop cap on the first paragraph of the section unless sections also get drop caps.
2. There was an article in *Serif* that discussed the typography of drop caps in some detail including the quotation mark case. It is not, unfortunately, available online although once I finish the LaTeX book, I’m considering putting together a best of *Serif* compilation that would likely include that article, assuming I can get the author's approval.³
3. The author contracts for *Serif* did explicitly include permission for a best of anthology reprint, but as a matter of courtesy, assuming that such a thing ever happens, I would still check with all the relevant authors as well as giving them a chance to do any revisions/updates that they might want to make.